# Searching a string from a line

Tags: java, string, parsing, search

After parsing a webpage i have found this line

"JANATAMF 7.30  -0.20    -2.67% 1STBSRS 80.00  -3.60    -4.31% 1STPRIMFMF 12.90  -0.80    -5.84% 6THICB 40.60  -2.50    -5.80% 8THICB 50.00  -1.30    -2.53% ABB1STMF 9.90  0.30    3.13% ACI   188.00     -5.90    -3.04% ACIFORMULA 82.70  0.50    0.61%"

now i want to find the corresponding integer value for any input such as
if i enter an input JANATAMF it will individually print 7.30  -0.20    -2.67%

i ve written a code but it does not look good..

```
public void stringfinder(String linktext,String input) throws NumberFormatException
{

    try
    {
        if(linktext!=null)
        {
            String finalstr=linktext;
            //System.out.print(finalstr);
            int inplen=input.length();
            if(finalstr.contains(input))               //CHECK THE USER INPUT IS IN STRING OR NOT WHICH RETURN BOOLEAN
             {
                //System.out.println("found");
                int index=finalstr.indexOf(input);      //FIND THE INDEX OR STARTING POINT OF THE STRING
                //System.out.print(index);
                int stpr=index+inplen+1;                  //AS WE VE TO PRINT THE NEXT STRING FROM THE INPUT STRING
                                                        //WE ADD THE STARTING POINT OF THE INPUT STRING AND THE LENGTH
                                                        //OF THE INPUT STRING
                //int first=0;
                int i=0;
                String x="" ;
                String ary[]=new String[10];
                while(finalstr.charAt(stpr)!=' ' )      //PRINT UNTIL FIND A GAP
                {
                    //System.out.print(finalstr.charAt(stpr));

                    Character c=new Character(finalstr.charAt(stpr));
                    String s=c.toString(c);
                    ary[i]=s;
                    x=x+ary[i];
                    i++;
                    stpr++;
                    //first++;
                }
                //System.out.print(x);
                String yo=x;
                System.out.print(yo);
                //double d = Double.valueOf(yo.trim()).doubleValue();

                /*int secstpr=stpr+1;
                int second=0;
                while(finalstr.charAt(secstpr)!=' ')
                {
                    System.out.print(finalstr.charAt(secstpr));
                    secstpr++;
                    second++;
                }*/
                //System.out.print(second);

             }

        }
```

}

so plz help...

Comment: You can try `string.split()`, and group by 4 items to build a `dict`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what @kev was referring to:

```
public String stringfinder(String linktext, String input) {
    String [] inputSplits = input.split("\\s+");
    for (int i = 0; i < inputSplits.length; i += 4) {
        if (inputSplits[i].equals(linktext) {
            return inputSplits[i + 1] + " " + inputSplits[i + 2]
                      + " " + inputSplits[i + 3];
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

This will return the string you were searching for. Still I would suggest that instead you concatenate the strings here: `return inputSplits[i + 1] + " " + inputSplits[i + 2] + " " + inputSplits[i + 3];` you interpret them more cleverly (e.g. construct numbers).